# Equivalent of js then() in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, typescript, concurrent.futures

In Typescript I'm used to writing async code like this:

```
async function foo()  // returns a promise
    return new Promise<string>( resolve, reject) {
       resolve('Hello!');
    });

async function bar() {
  s: string  = await foo();
}

async function baz() {
   foo().then((s: string) { alert(s); }
```

How would I go about doing this in python (>= 3.7.0)?
I guess this is correct:

```
async def bar:
    await s = foo()
```

But what about the python equivalents for `foo()` and `baz()`?  How would I write them?  Should I be using [concurrent.futures.Future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#future-objects) objects? If so, how?

Comment: Did you check out a basic tutorial in Python ``async``? The ``asyncio`` library has a few examples, as do most other ``async`` frameworks.. Python's "promises" (called awaitables) work less explicitly than what you have shown. While it is possible to do something akin to that depending on the ``async`` framework, it's not idiomatic style.

Comment: That is what I posted on solutions. sorry. take a look at the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html

Comment: Your TypeScript syntax isn't valid, and you're not returning anything from `bar`, so that function's a no-op...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's `async` support is syntactic sugar to *hide* awaitables, not to expose them. As such, one generally does not explicitly use the equivalent of a JS Promise – in most `async` frameworks a `Future` or `Task` – but the native language primitives.

```py
async def foo():
    return "Hello!"  # async function returns directly

async def bar():
    s = await foo()  # async function is await'ed

async def baz():
    print(await foo())  # await function to "then" use its result
```

The above code are just native primitives, and as such valid in *all* Python `async` frameworks, be it `asyncio`, `trio`, `curio` or others. Explicitly interacting with a Promise to add callbacks is not supported by all `async` frameworks – in fact, [many are explicitly designed to reject this notion](https://vorpus.org/blog/notes-on-structured-concurrency-or-go-statement-considered-harmful/).

---

The `asyncio` framework allows to add callbacks to both [`Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future) and [`Task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task) objects, which represent first-class concurrent actions (similar to a thread). Such operations are usually not `async` themselves, and can be done by regular functions.

```py
import asyncio

def qux():
    footure = asyncio.create_task(foo())
    footure.add_done_callback(lambda foot: print(f"The future said {foot.result()}"))
    return footure
```

Note that while `asyncio` exposes this functionality, it is considered exclusive to low-level use-cases.

> #### [add_done_callback(callback, *, context=None)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.add_done_callback)
>
> Add a callback to be run when the Task is done.
>
> *This method should only be used in low-level callback-based code.*

Comment: Every time I read an article like the one at your first link, I think about this essay:
[“Considered Harmful” Essays Considered Harmful](https://meyerweb.com/eric/comment/chech.html)

Answer (score 4):

The Python async/await syntax really looks like ECMAScript async/await syntax. There's no equivalent of `.then()`, just like you don't need `.then()` with async/await in ES.

The equivalent async Python code would be (with `bar()` elided as it did nothing):

```
import asyncio

async def foo():
    return 'Hello!'

async def baz():
    s = await foo()
    print(s)

asyncio.run(baz())
```